# Pronoun "something" in negative sentences

Tags: pronouns, indefinite-pronouns

I haven't found any information about a grammar rule that describes the possibility of somebody/something in negative sentences. In this sentence, for example:

> "Something is not right."

Please give me a reference to the rules explaining why we should use 'something' but not 'anything' in this sentence. Thank you in advance!

I checked the following websites/resources, but couldn't find any help:
[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/), [My English Teacher](https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/something-anything/), [EC English](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/anything-nothing-something-everything), [Word Reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/something-anything-affirmative-and-negative.2339383/), [Perfect English Grammar](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/something-anything-nothing-everything.html), [EF.com.](https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/indefinite-pronouns/), [Really Learn English](https://www.really-learn-english.com/which-one-is-correct-something-or-anything.html), and [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-something-and-anything).

Comment: Hello, Vadim. Please tell us which books / websites you've looked in / on, so that people here don't have to waste time checking there.

Comment: "There's something wrong" sounds more idiomatic.

Comment: @Adwin Ashworth Thank you, I've updated the question

Comment: [Any and its extensions anything, anywhere, anyone, etc. is a negative polarity item.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/515944/2637)

Comment: "*Some thing* is not right."

Comment: @Hot Licks https://ludwig.guru/s/something+isn't+right

Comment: @VadimKiselev - There is a *thing* that is not right.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think my example has a negative connotation... I haven't found the specific rule at this link. There is only subjective interpretation (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: @Hot Licks Your variant also exists, of course, but there are sentences with "something".

Comment: @FunbleFingers Am I right that using "something" as the singular (in general or when we are speaking about a concrete thing without an opened list) allows us to ignore the rule of the use "anything" in negative sentences (apart from some exceptions that are known)?

Comment: @VadimKiselev - The point isn't that there's a "variant".  The point is that *some thing* is missing.

Comment: "Something is not [quite] right [here] is a standard set phrase. "Something is missing" is a common sentence showing a 'statement of negative situation', but "Something is not here" would be rarer. "Something is not working" is fine. "Somebody [or other] is not here" would be expected only when the person's presence was expected.